# jest: output only ASCII characters in the reports

Tags: windows, unicode, emacs, jestjs

On a clean node project with Jest 24.9.0, this test suite

```
test('a test', () => {
    expect('foo').toBe('foo');
});

test('b test', () => {
    throw 'foo';
});
```

outputs the following (abbreviated):

```
  √ a test
  × b test (1ms)
  ● b test
```

The non-ASCII characters, especially the bullet, cause a significant slow-down in an Emacs buffer on Windows 10.

How can I instruct Jest to output only ASCII characters in its decorations?

Jest documentation is silent on the issue; grepping node_modules folder for these characters turned out nothing promising (directly related to Jest).

Comment: For people with Y problem (slow-down in a Emacs buffer with non-ASCII characters present), this might help:  https://github.com/zklhp/emacs-w64/issues/4#issuecomment-346273091

Answer (score 0):

I tried [various reporters](https://npmjs.com/search?q=jest+reporter), but not to my satisfaction. It's easiest to simply filter the report:

*package.json*

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jestwrapper"
    }
}
```

*bin/jestwrapper*

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
jest 2>&1 | perl -C -Mutf8 -lpe'tr/√✔✓✘✕●/+++xx-/'
```